# problema con pasar parametros a un Route desde javascript

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-7

he estado liado con pasar unos parametros que ya previamente comprobe que existen y tienen un valor, trato de construir un boton desde js, al ver tanto fallo he tratado de visualizar por medio de console.log que es lo que se construye

```js
var notas_periodo = 1;
var notas_parcial = 2;
var notas_jornada = 3;
var notas_modalidad = 4;
var notas_curso = 5;
var notas_seccion = 6;
var notas_materia = 7;
var notas=notas_periodo+","+notas_parcial+","+notas_jornada+","+notas_modalidad+","+notas_curso+","+notas_seccion+","+notas_materia;
console.log("<p style='color: green; font-size: 15px; font-weight: 700;' class='float-left'>Registro final </p><a href='{{ route('notas.descargar', "+notas+")}}'><button type='button' class='btn btn-success float-left'> Descargar</button></a>");
```

deberia obtener lo siguiente:

```html
<p style='color: green; font-size: 15px; font-weight: 700;' class='float-left'>Registro final </p><a href='{{ route('notas.descargar', 1,2,3,4,5,6,7)}}'><button type='button' class='btn btn-success float-left'> Descargar</button></a>
```

pero en ves de eso, recibo lo mismo que se codifico en js

Comment: PHP y por ende laravel se ejecuta en el servidor, mucho antes de que se ejecute js en el cliente. Por lo tanto no puedes mezclarlos

Answer (score 0):

las rutas o `{{ route('notas.descargar', 1,2,3,4,5,6,7)}}` solo se puede usar en blade no en archivos JS.

los archivos blade con trasnconpilados para poder reemplasar  `{{ route('turuta') }}`

yo lo que hago para poder usar rutas y otras cosas como `@if`  es crear una js.blade.php y dentro meto todo el script que yo necesite.

te aconsejo hacerlo para poder trabajar con rutas.

otra obcion seria usar variables globales para JS por ejemplo:

en mi JS tendria.

`function enviar(id){ $.get(MiRuta,{id:id},function(data){ }); }`

y en html en `<header><script>var MiRuta='';</script></header>`

y un pequeño codigo en la vista .blade
`<script> MiRuta='{{ route('TuRuta') }}';</script>`

esto haría un pequeño baypass entre tu js y la vista que pasa la ruta a la variable, y esta puede ser usada en el js sin problemas

Comment: muchas gracias por tu aporte, el archivo es blade, lo que trato de hacer es construir un boton en un div a partir de variables que manejo del resultado de una consulta  a bd, ya lo he logrado al construir un table y rellenar los datos desde js, pero con este boton no lo he logrado y no se si pasa por el tema de comillas simples y dobles

Comment: no deves hacer eso `href='{{ route('notas.descargar', "+notas+")}}'`  tienes que armar la url y alli recien después armarla en el JS